# Login failed for user 'CHIEF\PRODYCHDBX3$'

Tags: sql-server

I have a user trying to connect to sql server 2012 and is getting the following error.

> Login failed for user 'CHIEF\PRODYCHDBX3$'. Reason: Could not find a
>   login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: ].

The user in question only gets this error when connecting via VPN from home.  Inside the office they can connect just fine.  This issue just started this week and they have been working from home for months.  Could some kind of windows update impacted a setting? He tried connecting via windows and sql accounts and gets the same error. But I am able to work from home over the same VPN connection with no error.  This kind of implies some kind of setting on his machine may of changed.  Any one have any suggestions.  No other VPN SQL users are having this issue in our organization.   Thanks in advance.

read through blows to kind similar issue. I have tested other clients and they can connect fine.

error message when connecting using ssms

> Login failed for user 'CHIEF\PRODYCHDBX3$'. Reason: Could not find a
>   login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: ]

Network or specific instance cannot be found  is error in ssms

Comment: That cannot happen as long as the same user pointing to same server. have you verified doing `ping` while the user on VPN connection, probably DNS pointing his request to different server by some reason

Comment: Sounds like when the user is connected via VPN that Windows thinks it's running on a public network and so is blocking Windows authentication ports with the firewall. Do they have problems accessing other Windows authenticated resources?